# Threads hang using java.net.HttpURLConnection when it's a self https connection

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, java-io

I'm currently writing an API which requires to make an HTTPS connection from server A to itself. Using Jmeter to test, I find that threads are easily hang with even 10 threads starting simultaneously. But if the connection is made to a different server, the problem doesn't exist.  I used just a few lines of code to test it. It presents the same problem.

```
try {
        URL url = new URL("some URL that connects to the server itself");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setConnectTimeout(20000);
        con.setReadTimeout(30000);
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setDoInput(true);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        int count = 0;
        while (line != null) {
            count += line.length();
           line = reader.readLine();
        }
        //con.disconnect();
      }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Among 10 threads, only 2 of them return with the results as expected, all the other seems to be timed out with stack trace

```
[err] java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
[err]     at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
[err]     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
[err]     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
[err]     at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
[err]     at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
[err]     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:954)
[err]     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
[err]     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1371)
[err]     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
[err]     at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
[err]     at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
[err]     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1511)
[err]     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439)
[err]     at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionOldImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionOldImpl.java:224)
```

I enable the debug option with -Djavax.net.debug=all, here are some traces show on the console

```
Default Executor-thread-15, called closeInbound()
Default Executor-thread-15, fatal error: 80: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
%% Invalidated:  [Session-19, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
Default Executor-thread-15
, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:
fatal,
description = internal_error
Default Executor-thread-15, Exception sending alert: java.io.IOException: writer side was already closed.
```

My question is why does it has problems when making a connection to the server itself? Why do only two connections make it back everytime? How should I solve it?
I tried to set `http.maxConnections` to system property using 
`System.setProperty("http.maxConnections", String.valueOf(300));` but it didn't help.

Comment: maybe show your server side code.  Also why is the disconnect commented out?

Comment: This is most of the server side code I used to test the problem. I commented it out because once I set the Keep-Alive to the connection with con.setRequestProperty("Keep-Alive", "300");
        con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");If I call disconnect() on a connection , the keep-Alive won't take effect, right? It doesn't help whether I call disconnect or not anyway.